# How to dynamic add and remove element by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var roles = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];

  $.each(roles, function(){
    $(".div2").append("<div class='roles'><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i><span>" + this + "</span></div>");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".div2 .roles").click(function(){
    var role = $(this)
    $(".div1").append(role);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".div1 .roles").click(function(){
    var role = $(this)
    $(".div2").append(role);
  });
});
```

```css
.div1,.div2 {
  display:inline-block;
}

.div1 {
  width:200px;
  height:230px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right:6px;
  float:left;
}

.div2 {
  width:200px;
  height:230px;
  margin-right:10px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Now, I have two div area. Div2(Right) contain some elements and when I click on "add" button it will move to Div1(Left) But I use same concept to move it back to Div2, but not working. Did I missing something?

Another question, how do I change the image to

```
<i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
```

if the element was move to Div1 from Div2.

Comment: You need event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the elements are added dynamically, use delegated events handlers:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', ".div2 .roles", function(){
    var role = $(this)
    $(".div1").append(role);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', ".div1 .roles", function(){
    var role = $(this)
    $(".div2").append(role);
  });
});
```

These work by delegating responsibility (hence the name *delegated*) to an unchanging ancestor element (`document` is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient). In your example `.div1` & `.div2` would probably do (if they never change).

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.div2').on('click', ".roles", function(){
    var role = $(this)
    $(".div1").append(role);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.div1').on('click', ".roles", function(){
    var role = $(this)
    $(".div2").append(role);
  });
});
```

This works by listing for the events (e.g. click) to bubble up to the ancestor. It *then* applies the jQuery selector to only the elements in the bubble chain. It *then* applies the function to only the matching elements that caused the event. The upshot is the elements need only exist at click time and not when the click was registered.

### Notes:

- At the moment you have 3 DOM ready handlers. You could put a single DOM ready around the 3 blocks of code.
- A shorter version of the *DOM ready* handler is as follows:

e.g.

```
$(function(){
   // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to delegate for the events as they are dynamically added. Also you can use single click handler to achieve this.

add a common class to div1 and div2 element say `wrapperDiv`:

```
<div class="div1 wrapperDiv"></div>
<div class="div2 wrapperDiv"></div>
```

and then use:

```
$('.wrapperDiv').on('click','.roles',function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings('.wrapperDiv').append(this);
});
```

Comment: Given the tiny runtime overhead of a delegated event handlers (v.s. click speed), just going further up the ancestor tree would do (e.g. to `document`), rather than connect multiple delegated handler (good combining of the operations into one using the hierarchy though)

Answer (score 0):

As the event you register is directly apply on the elements in the div, they're behavior won't change no matter they're currently in `.div1` or `.div2`

You have to use `.on` to catch any delegated click events that its source is `.intro` from `.div1` or `.div2`'s children, and then move the target to another div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var roles = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];

  $.each(roles, function(){
    $(".div2").append("<div class='roles'><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i><span>" + this + "</span></div>");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".div2").on('click', '.roles', function(){
    var role = $(this);
    $(".div1").append(role.detach());
  });
  $(".div1").on('click', '.roles', function(){
    var role = $(this);
    $(".div2").append(role.detach());
  });
});
```

```css
.div1,.div2 {
  display:inline-block;
}

.div1 {
  width:200px;
  height:230px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right:6px;
  float:left;
}

.div2 {
  width:200px;
  height:230px;
  margin-right:10px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```